# Difference between Ctrl+Shift+F and Ctrl+I in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, auto-indent

I have been used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to correct indentation but I heard there is another shortcut to do that: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>

According a [reference](http://www.allapplabs.com/eclipse/eclipse_shortcuts.htm) found in google,
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> is Reformat
and
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> is Correct indentation.

Is there any difference between them? or between Reformat and Correct indentation?

Comment: You can go to Help > Key Assist... to get a _very_ short description of what shortcuts are.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

If you press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> it will just format tabs/whitespaces in code and pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> format all code that is format tabs/whitespaces and also divide code lines in a way that it is visible without horizontal scroll.

Comment: Ctrl + I works only if those tabs/whitespaces are at the beginning. It doesn't work if you have something like `int i = _____5;` ( _ = empty space ). Only Ctrl + Shift + F will convert this line to `int i = 5;`.

Answer (score 13):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> formats the selected line(s) or the whole source code if you haven't selected any line(s) as per the formatter specified in your Eclipse, while <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> gives proper indent to the selected line(s) or the current line if you haven't selected any line(s).

Comment: i think this is the correct answer because this is best used when you specify a formatter in eclipse.

Answer (score 6):

Reformat affects the whole source code and may rebreak your lines, while Correct Indentation only affects the whitespace at the beginning of the lines.

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl+Shift+F formats the selected line(s) or the whole source code if you haven't selected any line(s) as per the format specified in your Eclipse, while Ctrl+I gives proper indent to the selected line(s) or the current line if you haven't selected any line(s).
try this.
or more precisely

The Ant editor that ships with Eclipse can be used to reformat

> XML/XHTML/HTML code (with a few configuration options in Window >
> Preferences > Ant > Editor).
>
> You can right-click a file then
>
> Open With... > Other... > Internal Editors > Ant Editor
>
> Or add a file association between .html (or .xhtml) and that editor with
>
> Window > Preferences > General > Editors > File Associations
>
> Once open in the editor, hit ESC then CTRL-F to reformat.