# Regular expression in Java and in Eclipse?

Tags: java, regex, eclipse, string

I want to remove all empty linse in Java. In Eclipse I will use:

```
\n( *)\n (or "\r\n( *)\r\n" in Windows)
```

. But in Java it isn't work (I used:

```
str=str.replaceAll("\n( *)\n")
```

). How to do it in Java using replaceAll? Sample:

```
package example
○○○○
public ... (where ○ is space)
```

Comment: Try pressing `Ctrl+I` or `Ctrl+Shift+F` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068009/difference-between-ctrlshiftf-and-ctrli-in-eclipse

Comment: `replaceAll` takes a second argument.

Comment: But I have more than 1 000 files (I'm editing big library), so I can't use combination of Ctrl+I or +Shift+F.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this

```
java.util.regex.Pattern ws = Pattern.compile("[\r|\n][\\s]*[\r|\n]");
java.util.regex.Matcher matcher = ws.matcher(str);
str = matcher.replaceAll(" ");
```