# Can someone look over my curly braces?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, curly-braces

I don't understand the concept with curly braces. It's getting annoying. I have 4 open and 4 closing curly braces. Shouldn't this negate any errors with them then?

```
package net.androidbootcamp.starconstellations;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Pegasuss.class));
}
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Your parentheses from `b.setOnClickListener(` are never closed.

Comment: Compliments on the question title. Nothing quite compares to the SO Mechanical Turk to look over your curly braces :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using eclipse, press [Ctrl+Shift+F](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068009/difference-between-ctrlshiftf-and-ctrli-in-eclipse) to auto-indent, and then your code will be very easy to read and you'll be able to follow the blocks created by the curly braces.

It's always a good idea to keep the code correctly indented.

Comment: Actually the default is Ctrl+I ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your on click listener doesn't have a closing normal bracket ')':

```
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    ....
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Pegasuss.class));
            }
        });
    }

}
```

This code should do the trick. The problem is you need to close the parenthesis and the line b.setOnClickListener **(** *Your on click listener* **);**. I would also recommend formatting your code better in the future as it will make it easier to deal with parenthesis and bracket issues.